# Losing information using g_hash_table_new_full

Tags: c, malloc, free, glib

On a project im working on, in my main structure i use a g_hash_table_new_full to save/sort some infromation, to have a quick access.

This is the structure i use inside the hash

```
struct post {
    char* title;
    char* tags;
    long  id;
    long  parent_id;
    long  user_id;
    long best_answer_id;
    float best_answer_score;
    int   score;
    int reply_number;
};
```

I create the hash with the following line :

```
    GHashTable* g_hash_table_posts = g_hash_table_new_full(g_int_hash, g_int_equal , NULL , &free_post);
```

I pass NULL as the third parameter, since the key is a long so i dont need to free it. My free_post functions is the one i use to free the post:

```
void free_post(void* rip) {
    POST p = (POST) rip;
    if(p) {
    free(p->title);
    free(p->tags);
    free(p);
  }
}
```

Since the only things i allocate are the strings, i only free them and then the structure it self.

Now the issue is when i do a `g_hash_table_lookup` with the post id, i can only feed those who are questions (parentId = -1) when i look for one which is an answear (parentID != -1 ) it returns NULL, as it cant find it. 
If i delete the `free(p)` part from the `free_post` function it works just fine.

I can't understand why since, that function should not even being casted, it should only be used when i cast g_hash_table_destroy, which i haven't used it. So why am i loosing information?

Comment: Please include the code you use to insert and look up entries in the hash table, in your minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The issue was, the fucntion `g_hash_replace` and `g_hash_insert`(in case of the key already existing) will use the free function if it is given when creating the array.

So my problem was when i was replacing some value i was actually destroying what i had there. Hope this helps if someone has the same problem :)